# WPF Submenus of the ContextMenu suddenly disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to dynamically show menus and submenus related to a TreeViewItem, but I found a weird behaviour: the first time I right-click on the node, the menu and submenus appear correctly, then if I press escape and then I repeat the right-click on the node, the submenus dissapear. And after that, sometimes the submenus randomly appear or disappear.

I reduced the error to the following code (It's the minimum code to reproduce the error). Does anyone know how I can correct the code? I've been looking for days but I cannot find any solution.

Thank you.

[Image showing what happens..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxqEi.png)

.Net framework 4.6.1 and 4.7

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTester.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TreeView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyMenu}" ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Blue" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True" ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening">
            <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
                        </Style>

                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs args)
    {
        ((TreeViewItem)sender).ContextMenu.ItemsSource = GetCommands();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MyMenu> GetCommands()
    {
        return new MyMenu[]
        {
            new MyMenu("Pep", new[]
            {
                new MyMenu("x"),
                new MyMenu("y"),
                new MyMenu("z"),
            }),
            new MyMenu("fuz")
        };
    }
}

public class MyMenu : ICommand
{
    public MyMenu(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public MyMenu(string name, IEnumerable<MyMenu> items)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        items.ToList().ForEach(x => this.commands.Add(x));
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyMenu> Commands
    {
        get { return this.commands; }
    }

    private readonly ObservableCollection<MyMenu> commands = new ObservableCollection<MyMenu>();

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

---

**Note**: thanks to [Rowbear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47684550/7778826) I found the best solution.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTester.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTester"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TreeView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <local:IsInstanceOfTypeConverter x:Key="IsInstanceOfTypeConverter" />
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True" ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening">
            <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <!-- Style for MenuItem -->
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />

                            <Style.Triggers>

                                <!-- Style for MyMenu -->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsInstanceOfTypeConverter},
                                                               ConverterParameter={x:Type local:MyMenu}}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Commands}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                                </DataTrigger>

                                <!-- More types of menus and commands with different binding.. -->
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsInstanceOfTypeConverter},
                                                               ConverterParameter={x:Type local:MyMenu2}}"
                                             Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Actions}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>

                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

IsInstanceOfTypeConverter.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// This class tests if <code>value</code> is instance of the type indicated in <code>parameter</code>.
/// </summary>
public sealed class IsInstanceOfTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type type = parameter as Type;
        return (type != null) && type.IsInstanceOfType(value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("IsInstanceOfTypeConverter can only be used for one way conversion.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something odd where you're relying on a ContextMenu's ItemsSource for the top level list of menu items, but then relying on a hierarchicaldatatemplate to build a tree. Maybe it'll work in some cases - I haven't tried that strategy. However, changing your demo code's xaml to the below should get you to what you want:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1" IsExpanded="True" ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening">
            <TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Commands}"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TreeViewItem.ContextMenu>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Here I'm relying on MenuItem's ItemsSource to create my child menu items.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is working perfectly.
The reason why I was using this structure is because I’ve got more than one type of command, and the binding to ItemsSource is different in each of them. Based on your answer I found a solution using DataTriggers.